# Action buttons on cards are abnormally sized

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm using the **Bot framework Nodejs SDK** to send a Hero card to present the user with a question and 3 options.

In the webchat channel, it would be like this:

```
var card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
.title("Please chose from below options:")
.buttons([
    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "A green shirt", "A green shirt"),
    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "A blue shirt", "A blue shirt"),
    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "A red shirt", "A red shirt")
])

var msg = new builder.Message(session).attachments([card]);
builder.Prompts.text(session, msg);
```

The chat screen does display the options in the form of buttons but the size seems to be off.

[image]

How do I modify the code to render the buttons in appropriate sizes, side by side?

Comment: The large buttons are a known issue, discussed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1228

Comment: To display buttons side by side, you could try the solutions discussed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/685

Comment: Alternatively you could have your buttons in separate cards in a carousel

Comment: Could you reply back and let me know if you've got things figured out? For the large buttons, it seems `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the key