# What is the correct way to render options list as buttons in choice prompt?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to present options to the user to chose from in the form of buttons, like this:

```
builder.Prompts.choice( session, "Do you want to raise a ticket for this problem?", "Yes|No",
    {
        maxRetries: 3,
        retryPrompt: 'Sorry, that is not a valid input'
    },
    { 
        listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button 
    }
);
```

However, the web chat channel shows this like so:

[image]

Obviously there is something wrong in the way it is done, but I'm not sure what.
How do I correctly use choice prompts with buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure you prompt options to look like the below example. In your code, you separated the options out into two parameters. The method, as a result, is only seeing your first set of options and is defaulting to a simple list. Make this change and it will render correctly.

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Do you want to raise a ticket for this problem?", "Yes|No",
    {
        maxRetries: 3,
        retryPrompt: 'Sorry, that is not a valid input',
        listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button
    }
);
```

Comment: This renders buttons, but runs into another problem on webchat channel. The buttons are abnormally sized. Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53143997/action-buttons-on-cards-are-abnormally-sized